# UITableView in a Storyboard

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, initialization, storyboard

Hello stackoverflow's guys !

I got a issue and i don't know how to fix it...

I've got a StoryBoard with a UINavigationController which has a UIViewController as RootViewController. In this RootViewController i have 2 UIButton.

The first UIButton `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` a UICollectionViewController it works great.

The seconde UIButton `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` a UIViewController which has 2 UITableView. Here is my issue when i instantiate my UIViewController my 2 UITableView are well loaded BUT when i touch it ( scroll ) i got this error :

```
-[__NSCFType scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x752ff90
2012-11-21 10:22:49.300 Month[19992:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x752ff90'
```

But when i made it RootViewController everyworks as i want... so i got a crash only when the RootViewController instantiate my UIViewController.

this is how i instantiate my UIViewController when i press the UIButton :

```
  DayViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"calendarDay"];
```

Hope you can help me with those informations.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have an object that you're using as a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and that object is being released too early.  (`[__NSCFType scrollViewDidScroll:]` indicates that the message is being sent to a Core Foundation item, which probably means an object address is being reused for something else.)

The code you show for creating a `DayViewController` will assign the object to a local variable.  Assuming you're using ARC, if that's the object being used as the delegate, try assigning it to a strong property instead.  Such as:

```
// .h file
@property (nonatomic, strong) DayViewController *viewController;

// .m file
self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"calendarDay"];
```

Comment: Yes ! Thanks !! ARC Gniiiiaa !